# Can't install/uninstall PHP Modules

Tags: linux, php, opensuse

I can't install or uninstall any php modules.

Is it because my `php -i` returns none for loaded configuraiton file?

```
 php -i | grep -i loaded
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

How can I solve it and why is no configuration file loaded?

### Demonstration

(show output of `php -m`, delete module php7-phar, show output of `php -m` again):

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]
```

---

```
zypper rm php7-phar
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 2 packages are going to be REMOVED:
  php-composer php7-phar

2 packages to remove.
After the operation, 2.1 MiB will be freed.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y): y
(1/2) Removing php-composer-1.6.5-lp150.1.1.noarch ....................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
(2/2) Removing php7-phar-7.2.5-lp150.1.7.x86_64 .......................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
There are some running programs that might use files deleted by recent upgrade. You may wish to check and restart some of them. Run 'zypper ps -s' to list these programs.
```

---

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar    // <-- should not be there anymore
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]
```

### More Information

#### php -i | grep ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php7/apache2
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
```

Comment: Is your problem with Phar specifically? Because it's built-in to PHP since 5.3; removing it won't do anything. You'd need to recompile with `--disable-phar`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php

Comment: Phar was only an example. It does not mather what I try to uninstall or install, the output of `php -m` does never change.

Comment: What's the output of `php -i | grep ini`? What distribution are you using?

Comment: I added the output to my question. I am using `Linux version 4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 7.4.1 20190905 [gcc-7-branch revision 275407] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Tue Nov 12 16:32:38 UTC 2019 (c939e24)`

Comment: What's in `/etc/php7/apache2`?

Comment: Three files `php.ini, php.ini.rpmnew, php.ini.rpmsave`

Comment: and there's nothing about modules in `/etc/php7/apache2/php.ini`?

Comment: There are a few lines with `extension=xyz` but this only affects the PHP which is loaded by the webserver.

Comment: How certain of that are you? If `php -i | grep ini` shows Apache paths even in the CLI, that may mean they share a `php.ini`.

Comment: But I get `Loaded Configuration File => (none)`, so it does not have a ini file and probably loads default settings all the time.
I rebuild PHP from source with `./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli` now it loads the ini from `/etc/php7/cli` I try to change something in this ini and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I uncommented the line `extension=bz2` but now I get `Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2'` when calling `php -i` but thats another problem...

Comment: I suspect you have somehow installed multiple conflicting versions of PHP. You should check for this. Probably you should delete both versions and start over.

Comment: The problem is, that the modules are outdatet:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module | Module compiled with module API=20170718 | PHP    compiled with module API=20180731 | These options need to match`

And I have no clue how I can update them. Do I have to build each one of them from source for my PHP version?